# Nonsingular Z-Matrix <==> Nonsingular M-Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here I'm considering only M-matrices that are also Z-matrices, so all the off diagonal elements are negative in all matrices I consider.

If I have a Z-Matrix with real, positive eigenvalues, is it also a nonsingular $M$-matrix? (Not sure if the real part is important).

If not, what is a counter-example, and would the additional assumption of symmetry help?

Best,
John

Comment: what is an M-matrix and Z-matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix is often called a $Z$-matrix if its off-diagonal entries are *nonpositive*. Your definition of $Z$-matrices is a bit different: you require the off-diagonal entries to be *negative*.

Put this discrepancy aside, if a $Z$-matrix has real positive eigenvalues, it is an $M$-matrix *by definition* (an $M$-matrix is a $Z$-matrix whose eigenvalues over $\mathbb C$ have positive real parts) and it is also a nonsingular matrix because it has not any zero eigenvalue. So, the answer to your question is affirmative.

Comment: Thanks! And yes I meant nonpositive, typo.